# What Is The Regex To Replace This Specific html code With That Particular Code?

Tags: php, html, session, tags

I have some html code in a $_SESSION.
One of the tags are:

```
</form>
```

Now, I want to replace that tag with:

```
</fieldset><fieldset>
```

How to achieve this ?

Following not working:

```
str_replace('</form>','</fieldset><fieldset>',$_SESSION['html_form_builder']);
```

I believe I will have to use preg_replace() instead. Will not str_replace() work if I try replacing symbols other than alpha-numerical chars ?

And, don't close this thread saying other threads exist teaching how to replace html code with preg_replace() because those threads' regex codes are no use to me as I am weak on regex. I actually need that specific regex to achieve my purpose.

Comment: I don't see why `str_replace()` would not work here. Is that the sole code or are you assigning it to a variable/outputting it?

Comment: Searching for `</form>` via regex or as plain text is the exact same. Please define the issue more. What you have would work (well also possibly breaking DOM structure, which regex would do as well).

Comment: @brombeer, Sorry! My mistake, I did not assign it to a variable.  It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex would be something like

```
preg_replace('</form>', '</fieldset><fieldset>', $_SESSION['html_form_builder']);
```

But when i run that code i get an extra ">" which only disappears if i write

```
preg_replace('</form>', '/fieldset><fieldset', $_SESSION['html_form_builder']);
```

So the fieldset tags don't have the starting and ending <>

This is because the <> tags are used as delimiters in the str_replace and preg_replace functions. So str_replace would also work if you did:

```
str_replace('/form','/fieldset><fieldset', $_SESSION['html_form_builder']);
```

Comment: Your test results are spot-on! Accepted your answer.